# create static object from class that act like method

Tags: java, constructor

I'm bit confused with the scripts that I saw recently. I want some explanation about it. I googled it and found that, this mechanism is being used from while but I couldn't understand it . Please don't downgrade my question if there any wrong.

I'm an android developer and start to being legend. :D

```
public final class ClassName{

    public static ClassName initSDK(@NonNull @GuiContext Context context) {
        return new ClassName(context);
    }   

    private ClassName(Context guiContext) {
        startSDK(guiContext);
    }

}
```

**what is *`initSDK`***. how it's call and what is the mechanism?

Thank you for your valuable time!

Comment: initSDK is the name of a method. stop doing Android, start with the basics of Java instead.

Comment: Looks like you're just asking what a "factory method" is.

Comment: @David Perhaps not. The annotations here looks important - there might be a framework involved that calls this method.

Comment: @Stultuske yeah it's a name of the method. But look the return type of that method. What the purpose of creating method and returning object within the same class ?

Comment: "What the purpose of creating method and returning object within the same class?" See [Factory method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

Comment: @David yeah, I wanted to know is this any kind of design pattern or any?

Comment: @EJChathuranga how else would you get an instance of ClassName in another class? the constructor is private, so it's not possible to retrieve one from the constructor, that's why you need to call that method.

Comment: @EJChathuranga it resembles a Singleton, but it isn't one, Factory can be like this.

Answer (score 1):

`initSDK` here is a `static method`, which you call it through it's class name, such as:

```
ClassName instance1 = ClassName.initSDK(context);
```

Internally, it creates an `object instance` of `ClassName` & return it. For example, `instance1` here is an instance of `ClassName`.

Note that the class constructor `private ClassName(Context guiContext) { .. }` is declared `private`, which means you can't instantiate this object via below method:

```
// Wrong, can't instantiate object this way. Constructor is declared "private"
ClassName instance2 = new ClassName(context);
```

Similar to `initSDK`, sometimes this similar method is named `getInstance()`, which indicates `get me an instance of the object`, access through the package name.

Comment: Yeah, What the purpose of private constructor? I think we can use directly **singleton pattern**  instead of above mechanism.

Comment: @EJChathuranga This is not `singleton`. Everytime `ClassName.initSDK(context);` is called, a different instance of `ClassName` object is returned, as it `new` an object each time. Whereas for `singleton`, it only `new` the object first time, subsequent call will return the `same object instance`.

Comment: Then why constructor is private? What the purpose?

Comment: Is this kind of security protocol?

Answer (score 0):

You can call it with `ClassName.initSDK()` from another class. It's a static method. Refer to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is a creational pattern called Factory Pattern, it hides the creation logic

Example of usage:

```
public interface MyFile {
    public String getContent(String filename);
}

public class MyCSVFile impelments MyFile {
    public String getContent(String filename) {
        // proper implementation on how to open and read CSV file
    }   
}

public class MyPDFFile impelments MyFile {
    public String getContent(String filename) {
        // proper implementation on how to open and read PDF file
    }   
}


public class MyFactory {

    public MyFile factory(String filename) {
        String ext = // utility to get file extension ...
        if (ext.equals("pdf")) {
            return new MyCSVFile(filename);
        }
        if (ext.equals("csv")) {
            return new MyPDFFile(filename);
        }

        // unhandled operation ? setup a default file reader ?
        // ...
    }
}

public class MyBusinessClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyFile myFile = new MyFactory().factory(args[1]);
        System.out.println(myFile.getContent(args[1]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*initSDK* is a factory method to produce an instance of *ClassName* as its *constructor* is *private* and cannot be invoked from outside. So we need some public which can be accessed without creating a new instance, therefore *public static* type method is available.

> Why not to make the constructor private? 
>   Because giving factory is intended to control object creation mechanism.